# ng-href url not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-href

I don't know why `ng-href` isn't working.
What i want to do is go from a `modal` to a `view`, passing the parameters `{{user}}` and `{{email}}`

here's the state

```
//gestion
.state('gestion',
{
url:'/compte/gestion/:user/:email',
templateUrl:'templates/gestion.html',
controller:'loginCtrl'  
})
```

code from the controller

```
$scope.goToState = function () {
$state.go('gestion', {user:'$scope.user', email: '$scope.email'});}
```

$scope.user and $scope.email are two values i retrieve from an external url

and here's the line from the `view` with the `ng-href`

```
<ion-item ng-click="goToState()" style="width:340px;margin-top:10px" >
Gerer mon compte
</ion-item>
```

thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ng-href` use `ng-click`. Because `ng-href` is for anchor tags.

```
<ion-item ng-click="goToState()" style="width:340px;margin-top:10px" >
Gerer mon compte
</ion-item>
```

In your controller, add the function

```
$scope.goToState = function () {
    $state.go('gestion', {user: 'User', email: 'example@gmail.com'});
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution.when i click on the item,the other view doesn't appear.no errors or warnings.=

Comment: Just make sure that you are passing the valid parameters in `$state.go()`. I jsut mentioned sample. Show me your code(update your code in the question)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` ??

you can use instead `ui-sref="gestion({ user: user , email : email })"`

Comment: i don't know what's $locationProvider is  and your solution if i change the ng-href,i would need to change the state url too?

Comment: @RatedAce if you are not using the first line don't worry about it. You can use `ui-sref` with no change. if not working you can stick with @Mr_Perfect `ng-click`

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by accident.i was in a modal.the modal was covering the entire screen.i had closeModal() implemented already but totally forgot to include it in ng-click.totally forgot about it.so the view was there just couldn't see it.
anyway thanks for help